# Is necessary to assume finite codimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

This is a question of Lax's Functional analysis book. Ch. 2 ex 8.

Let $N$ be a subspace of the linear space $X$ and $Y$ be a complementary subspace of $N$. Show that if $N$ has finite codimension then $\dim Y = \text{codim } N$.

I have used the linear map $T: Y \rightarrow X / N$ that maps $y \mapsto [y]$ and proved that is a isomorphism. But I don't see the necessity of the hypothesis that $N$ has finite codimension.

Comment: What is codim X? Do you mean codim N?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo

Comment: The difficulty with infinite dimension is that not everybody means the same thing all the time. If the dimension is the cardinal of an algebraic basis then the same proof goes through.